# illegal string body character after dollar sign in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, hashicorp-vault

I am able to fetch VAULT Secrets from shell script "vault kv get -field=vCenter test/hello" but unable to do same using Jenkins pipeline  because of the syntax.

```
cd $WORKSPACE@script && ./getvms.py -u zzz -p $(vault kv get -field=vCenter test/hello
```

**error**
*WorkflowScript: 5: illegal string body character after dollar sign;
solution: either escape a literal dollar sign "$5" or bracket the value expression "${5}" @ line 5, column 81.
reLinuxBuild@fplu.fpl.com -p $(vault kv*

Comment: That error doesn't look like it comes from that line of script

Comment: hi @lxop Thanks for looking into i have to use VAULT fetch command which is -p **$(**vault kv get -field=vCenter**)**  jenkinsfile is showing error because of using **$** 

Solution is jenkins needs to skip $ so i have added -p **\$(**vault kv get -field=vCenter**)

this is working fine now